# array en POSTGRESQL con numeros y letras

Tags: array, postgresql

Tengo el siguiente problema:

```
select array['asda','uu','aseda']; // si son solo letras funciona.

select array[1,2,3]; // si son solo numeros funciona.
```

pero necesito un array con ambas como el siguiente ejemplo:

```
select array[1,'uu','asd']; // con  letras y numeros.
```

Alguna idea?

Comment: Que quiere decir que no funciona? recibis algun error? que es lo que deberia pasar? que es lo que pasa? usa el boton [edit] y agrega toda esa info en la pregunta...

Comment: Hola necesito un array  como lo indica la segunda parte select array[1,'uu','asd']; que contenga letras y numeros. muchas gracias.

Comment: Puedes castearlo a `text[]` y todos los elementos se convertirán a string, no puedes tener distintos tipos en el array. `select array[1,'uu','asd']::text[]`

Comment: y que es lo que no funciona?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que tengo entendido, es que los arrays son declarados con **1 solo tipo de dato**, es decir, si yo declaro un array `integer` no puedo seleccionarlo como un *string*. Existe una posibilidad de seleccionar los array con ambos valores pero para ello debes crear un **array multidimensional**

Ejemplo:

Creamos la tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE sal_emp (
    name            text,
    pay_by_quarter  integer[],
    schedule        text[][]
);
```

Poblamos con 1 campo:

```
INSERT INTO sal_emp
    VALUES ('Carol',
    '{20000, 25000, 25000, 25000}',
    '{{"breakfast", "consulting"}, {"meeting", "lunch"}}');
```

Y el select:

```
SELECT * FROM sal_emp;

 name  |      pay_by_quarter       |                 schedule
-------+---------------------------+-------------------------------------------
 Carol | {20000,25000,25000,25000} | {{breakfast,consulting},{meeting,lunch}}
```

Pero a fin de cuentas, si lo vez todos los valores son *string* independiente del tipo de dato.

Te dejo la [documentación oficial de PostgreQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/arrays.html) en su versión 9.2

Suerte

Comment: gracias, pense que se podia pero ya me aclaraste la duda.